# From Rgb to Cmyk

Tags: code-golf, conversion, color

Given 3 bytes or RGB as input, calculate the nearest CMYK values, and output them.

- create either a function with parameters and return value or a program that operates on stdin/stdout
- use the color profile of your choice, but provide a reference
- input may be either separate numeric values in range [0;255] or a 6 digit hex string
- output should be separate numeric values ranging either [0;1] or [0;100]
- standard code golf: [no loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), shortest code wins
- extravagant ideas are welcome

sample data:

```
input             output
108,174,106       [0.3793103448275862, 0.0, 0.3908045977011494, 0.3176470588235294]
0,0,0             0,0,0,1
170,255,238       33,0,7,0  
0x0088ff          1,0.4667,0,0
[250,235,215]     [0,6,14,1.96]  
#123456           .7907,.3953,0,.6627
```

- Uncalibrated mapping is fine and probably the easiest
- No input validation required; floats are allowed (ranging from 0 to 255), but may also be rounded
- Output format should be either clearly commented or obvious; i.e.:

  1. CMYK in that order
  2. does not matter if percentage [0;100] or pure numbers [0;1]
- Testing should include the trivial example [0,0,0].

[This site](http://codebeautify.org/rgb-to-cmyk-converter) has the most digits of online tools that I could find. Does anyone know a tool that gives more than 4 digits?

Comment: Can the input be floats between 0 to 1?

Comment: Could you give some example inputs/outputs?

Comment: Also, welcome to PPCG. :) Usually we put challenges first in the [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for ± 72 hours. That way people can give feedback and your challenge will overall improve before you post it here.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Just a side note, but I don't think that's how you use ±...

Comment: @LeakyNun In my understanding it means something like _More or less / roughly_ in the English language [see the adverb section here for some examples](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plus-minus). I personally prefer it over ≈. Although according to Wikipedia it is mostly used in mathematics and such, in that case the usage is indeed wrong.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh, thanks for teaching.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a decent challenge, but it's a little bit unclear. I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking, but if you explain the algorithm to convert them and provide some test-cases, I will retract my vote.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen In the adverb section, it says *South African*. It's not used that way in standard English. We use `~`.

Comment: The close vote message is a bit misleading, because it stems from our Q&A roots, but it was indeed "put on hold as unclear what you're asking". There were a couple of requests for clarification in the comments which weren't addressed: specifically whether inputs and outputs as floats between 0 and 1 are allowed (or whether it has to be integers from 0 to 255), how the conversion actually works, and whether you could include some test cases.

Comment: Is it required to always have a 0 in at least one of `CMY`?

Comment: @l4m2 I don´t think so; but I guess that there are RGBs for which the result does not contain a `0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
1-⊢(÷,255÷⍨⊢)⌈/
```

1 minus `1-`
 ***X*** divided by `÷` ***Y***, followed by `,` 255 dividing `255÷⍨` ***Y*** `⊢`, where
  ***X*** is itself `⊢` (i.e. the list of RGB values), and
  ***Y*** is the max `/⌈` (of the RGB values).

$$
\begin{cases}
J = max(R,G,B)\\
C = 1-\frac{R}{J}\\
M = 1-\frac{G}{J}\\
Y = 1-\frac{B}{J}\\
K = 1-\frac{J}{255}\\
\end{cases}
$$

[TryAPL!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u21901-%u22A2%28%F7%2C255%F7%u2368%u22A2%29%u2308/%20%u22C4%20f%20108%20174%20106&run)

**Credits:**
 ∘ -1 byte by [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn).

Comment: When is PPCG getting MathJax?

Comment: @Neil http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=MathJax

Comment: +1 for `⍨`! Nice emoticon

Comment: @programmer5000 Thank you. You'll find that one in pretty much all my code-golfs. It swaps the arguments of the function to its left. Other APL emoticons are `⍣` and `⍤`. I hope we'll get `⍥` and `⍢` soon.

Comment: @Adám `ಠ` would make me happy!

Comment: @programmer5000 J is the master emoticon language though (albeit they face the opposite way of normal smilies). Check the third column [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/vocabul.htm).

Comment: @programmer5000 NARS2000 APL has [`⊙`](http://wiki.nars2000.org/index.php/Null). Good enough?

Answer (score 8):

## [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```
(r,g,b)=>{float[]a={r,g,b,1};var j=a.Max();a[3]=j*j/255;return a.Select(x=>1-x/j);};
```

output for `108,174,106`:

```
0.3793104
0
0.3908046
0.3176471
```

Since OP allows function I submitted only the lambda. You can find a running demo on [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/alJ6Ah). I am not a golfer, I post for fun. Also, it is my first answer \o/. Feel free to comment any improvement :)

Kudos to Leaky Nun for the formula.

caveat: it doesn´t work for [0,0,0] (thank you Titus)

Comment: `1.0-x/j`? You surely can't do `1-x/j`?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ yes I can! It was a rest from an experience. The goal was to auto cast to double. I remove it.

Comment: You don't need it for subtraction anyways. Also, you don't seem to re-use `a[3]`, and you don't seem to specify a fixed size for `a`, so you can do `{r,g,b}` and `a[3]=j*j` (because, anyways, `1 * a = a`).

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ I am reusing `a` with the `select()`.  If I use `a[3]` like this I will out of range and throw, wont I?

Comment: I mean, assigning it first.

Comment: Like this `a[3]=j*j/255;`? Indeed it works.

Comment: Yeah that one, and removing the `,1` in `{r,g,b,1}`? I don't think *assigning first* will cause any "out of range" errors.

Comment: If I write `double[]a={r,g,b};`, it throws.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Comment: Great first answer and welcome to PPCG! If you want to display your language and bytes in a larger font like the other answers (which is usually the standard here), you can add a `#` in front of the line. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you :)

Comment: nice approach; though it doesn´t work for [0,0,0]

Comment: @Titus Indeed. I forgot it!

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 46 bytes

```
lambda*c:[1-i/max(c)for i in c]+[1-max(c)/255]
```

Requires input to be floats in Python 2, fairly sure it doesn't in 3.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>58</s> 51 bytes

```
a=>[...a.map(e=>1-e/m||1,m=Math.max(...a)),1-m/255]
```

Accepts an array `[R, G, B]` (add 7 bytes for separate parameters) and returns an array `[C, M, Y, K]` using the uncalibrated colour mapping.

Comment: Are you sure with the order CYMK on your second answer? looks like CMYK to me.

Comment: 2) Do you know why spreading of `a` mixes up its content? This is weird.  3) Have you tested [0,0,0]? No exception in ES, but looks like a division by zero.

Comment: Sorry, they were both CMY, that was my fault. Now also fixed the [0,0,0] cases.

Comment: 4) Try `[...a,m=Math.max(...a)]` in your array solution. 5) Can you golf the other one further using an array as input? Consider using `a.0` etc. instead of `.map`.

Comment: @Titus I've come up with a completely new approach now which actually prefers CMYK order and saves 7 bytes too!

Comment: 1) Do I get it right that `||1` replaces infinity with `1`? ES is wicked! 2) Does `m` really stay defined outside the `map` call? 3) I accept the array; but what would it look with separate parameters?

Comment: @Titus 1) `0/0` is `NaN`, which counts as falsy 2) Yes, it sets the global variable `m` (so invalid in strict mode) 3) `([...a])=>` etc.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <del>36</del> <del>28</del> 33 bytes

```
List@@ColorConvert[{##}/255,"CMYK"]&
```

<del>After liberalization of I/O formats, golfed further: `List@@#~ColorConvert~"CMYK"&`</del>

Anonymous function, that does what is asked.

The old function takes three arguments from 0 to 255 (anything beyond this range will be automatically clipped to this range) and returns an array of "CMYK" values between `0.` and `1.`

Example (for old function):

```
List @@ ColorConvert[{##}/255, "CMYK"] &[108, 174, 106]
```

> ```
> {0.37931, 0., 0.390805, 0.320313}
> ```

Since arrays are allowed as input, **33 bytes:**

```
List@@ColorConvert[#/255,"CMYK"]&
```

*Of course* the *built-in* function handles `{0, 0, 0}` properly and returns `{0, 0, 0, 1}`.

Comment: 1) To clarify: input values must be in [0;255]. will edit the question in a minute, 2) Please test [0,0,0]. 3) Shouldn´t that be `/255`?

Comment: @Titus you're right, its 255, can't address all issues at the moment though, I'll fix things at earliest convenience

Comment: @Titus fixed it

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>24</s> <s>21</s> <s>18</s> <s>24</s> 21 bytes

Life is a round trip, indeed.

```
=cR255Q+mc--1dK-1JeSQJQK
=cR255Q+mc-JeSQdJQ-1J
+mc-JeSQdJQ-1cJ255
+mc-JeSQd+J^T_15Q-1cJ255
+m-1?JeSQcdJ1Q-1cJ255
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bm-1%3FJeSQcdJ1Q-1cJ255&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=108%2C174%2C106%0A0%2C0%2C0&debug=0)

Sample input: `108,174,106`

Sample output: `[0.3793103448275862, 0.0, 0.3908045977011494, 0.3176470588235294]`

Sample input: `0,0,0`

Sample output: `[0, 0, 0, 1.0]`

Formula used:

$$
\begin{cases}
J = max(R,G,B)\\
C = 1-\frac{R}{J}\\
M = 1-\frac{G}{J}\\
Y = 1-\frac{B}{J}\\
K = 1-\frac{J}{255}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Old formula: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtPD6.gif

Old formula: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqi9F.gif

Comment: nice golfing. care for a breakdown?

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + ImageMagick, 69 bytes

```
convert "xc:$1[1x1]" -colorspace cmyk txt:-|grep -o '([^)]*)'|head -1
```

Example:

```
$ ./rgb2cmyk.sh "#6CAE6A"
(38%,0%,39%,32%)

$ ./rgb2cmyk.sh "#000000"
(0%,0%,0%,100%)

$ ./rgb2cmyk.sh "#AAFFEE"
(33%,0%,7%,0%)

$ ./rgb2cmyk.sh "#0088ff"
(100%,47%,0%,0%)

$ ./rgb2cmyk.sh "#FAEBD7"
(0%,6%,14%,2%)

$ ./rgb2cmyk.sh "#123456"
(79%,40%,0%,66%)
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```
INPUT R,G,B
J=MAX(R,G,B)IF!J THEN?0,0,0,1 ELSE?1-R/J,1-G/J,1-B/J,1-J/255
```

Could be much shorter.

Comment: Did you mean to write `J=MAX(R,G,B)` ?

Answer (score 2):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 114 bytes

```
#R,G,B::((var J(max R G B))(if(!= 0 J)((list(- 1(/ R J))(- 1(/ G J))(- 1(/ B J))(- 1(/ J 255))))((list 0 0 0 1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/lithp-webide/?code=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)

- Saved 6 bytes (forgot that `max` takes any number of arguments)

I'm not quite sure this is right. The first two results with the sample data are correct, but the rest are not (see the [Try it online](https://andrakis.github.io/lithp-webide/?code=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).)

Uses the implementation described nicely as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
J = max(R,G,B)\\
C = 1-\frac{R}{J}\\
M = 1-\frac{G}{J}\\
Y = 1-\frac{B}{J}\\
K = 1-\frac{J}{255}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 7, <s>123</s> <s>110</s> 105 bytes

**Input as RGB color `100 240 75`**

```
$j=max($h=$argv);echo strtr(@(1-$h[1]/$j).",".@(1-$h[2]/$j).",".@(1-$h[3]/$j).",".(1-$j/255),["NAN"=>0]);
```

Outputs CMYK values as decimal in `0...1` range.

Saved lots of bytes thanks to Titus.

Sample usage:

```
php -r '$j=max($h=$argv...' 100 240 75
0.58333333333333,0,0.6875,0.058823529411765

php -r '$j=max($h=$argv...' 255 255 255
0,0,0,0

php -r '$j=max($h=$argv...' 0 255 0
1,0,1,0

php -r '$j=max($h=$argv...' 0 0 0 
0,0,0,1
```

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5a56352fd3f7cf7a6f75fdc9e3143b57af97425)

---

**Input as HEX color `#123456`, 202 bytes**

```
$h=str_split(substr($argv[1],-6),2);$j=max($r=hexdec($h[0]),$g=hexdec($h[1]),$b=hexdec($h[2]));echo z($r,$j),",",z($g,$j),",",z($b,$j),",",1-$j/255;function z($c,$y){return is_nan(@($c/$y))?0:1-$c/$y;}
```

54 bytes for function to prevent division by zero, probably golfable or removable.

Gets as input RGB color as HEX `#123456` and outputs CMYK as decimal in `0...1` range.

Sample usage:

```
php -r '$h=str_split...' '#000000'
0,0,0,1

php -r '$h=str_split...' '#ffffff'
0,0,0,0

php -r '$h=str_split...' '#123456'
0.7906976744186,0.3953488372093,0,0.66274509803922

php -r '$h=str_split...' '#ffff00'
0,0,1,0
```

Comment: `separate numeric values` means you can just take `$h=$argv;` and use `$h[1]` instead of `$h[0]` etc. I like the `NAN` trick; but doesn´t that yield warnings? `strtr` is probably shorter than `str_replace`, and `NAN` needs no qotation (will yield Notices, but those are not displayed in the default config).

Comment: Also, please provide the PHP version this works in. It does not in PHP 7 (where `1/0` results in `INF`) nor in PHP 5 (`1/0` => `false`).

Comment: @Titus Thanks for the very interesting `$argv` array tip in command line! I added the PHP version. It works with `NAN` because when you use `str_replace` it converts implicitly the number to string so it outputs `NAN`, in fact if you check at [this link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/900f4c4b61a53f9147d1308318f46944acccab3e), you will see that it outputs `NAN` because of `str_replace("INF"` instead of `str_replace("NAN"`. I couldn't make it work using `strtr`. I added the `@` to suppress the warnings.

Comment: I found my mistake: `$n/0` is `INF`, but `0/0` is `NAN` (also in PHP 7.0). You can save 4 bytes with `str_replace(NAN,0,$s)` or 6 bytes with `strtr($s,["NAN"=>0)`.

Comment: @Titus great thanks, I couldn't figure out how to properly use `strtr()`;

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, not competing

I was just too tempted to post my own.

**RGB input, 74 bytes**

```php
for(;$i++<4;)echo$i<4?($j=max($argv))?1-$argv[$i]/$j:0:1-$j/255,","[$i>3];
```

or 68 bytes with a trailing comma in the output: remove `[$i>3]`.

Run with `php -r '<code>' <red-value> <green-value> <blue-value>`.

**HEX input, 100 bytes**

```php
foreach($a=array_map(hexdec,str_split($argv[1],2))as$c)echo($j=max($a))?1-$c/$j:0,",";echo 1-$j/255;
```

Run with `php -nr '<code>' RRGGBB`.

That approach would take 75 bytes for RGB input:
replace `foreach($a=array_map...as$c)` with `foreach($a=$argv as$c)if($i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 155 bytes

```
#define C(x) 1-x/(j>0?j:1)
#define F float
i=0;F j;f(F r,F g,F b){j=(r>g?r:g)>b?(r>g?r:g):b;for(;i++<4;)printf("%f\n",i>1?i>2?i>3?1-j/255:C(b):C(g):C(r));}
```

I'm trying to figure out how it's possible golf more.

### Usage:

```
#define C(x) 1-x/(j>0?j:1)
#define F float
i=0;F j;f(F r,F g,F b){j=(r>g?r:g)>b?(r>g?r:g):b;for(;i++<4;)printf("%f\n",i>1?i>2?i>3?1-j/255:C(b):C(g):C(r));}
main(){
    f(108,174,106);
}
```

#### Output:

```
0.379310
0.000000
0.390805
0.317647
```

Comment: 1) +3: mistake: function should return the result, not print it. (sorry I just saw that)
2) +4: error: i is not declared.
3) +0: error: your ternary operators seem off. shouldn´t that be `i>0?i>1?i>2`

Comment: but there is some golfing potential; I found -25 bytes in ANSI C, and another -19 in C99. 2 bytes are here: `j>0?`,17 in getting rid of the loop, and 6 in splitting up the `j` definition.

Comment: add another +3 for the function: it returns something else than int, so a return type is required (`F *`). But I found another byte to golf away in C99.

Comment: @Titus If I'm not mistaken, `j>0?j:1` can be `j+!j` to achieve -3 bytes.

Comment: And I think the `C` macro is incorrect: `1-x/1` for `j==0`? I think that should be `1-(j>0?x/j:1)`.

Answer (score 0):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 110 bytes

```
=>
rs
|*
a/*
=+
[s=(cury sub .1) j=(roll a max)]
(welp (turn a |*(* (s (min .1 (div +< j))))) (s (div j .255)))
```

Use the single precision floating-point library.
Create a new generic function that takes `a`.
Set `s` to `sub` curried with `.1` for later, and `j` to folding over `a` with `max`.

Map over `a` by dividing each element with `j`, finding the minimum of that and 1 to normalize NaN, then subtract 1 with `s`. Add `1-j/255` to the end of that list.

```
> =f =>
  rs
  |*
  a/*
  =+
  [s=(cury sub .1) j=(roll a max)]
  (welp (turn a |*(* (s (min .1 (div +< j))))) (s (div j .255)))
> (f (limo ~[.108 .174 .106]))
[i=.3.7931037e-1 t=[i=.0 t=[i=.3.908046e-1 .3.1764704e-1]]]
> (f (limo ~[.0 .0 .0]))
[i=.0 t=[i=.0 t=[i=.0 .1]]]
```

Comment: Can you provide a TiO please.

Comment: @Titus: Hoon doesn't have a TiO site, unfortunately.